# How to parse file containing hexadecimals in the form -0x1.0c7474fp+8 in c++?

Tags: c++, parsing, hex, fstream, iostream

I am trying to parse a file `data.txt` containing **hexadecimals** of the form `-0x1.0c7474fp+8`:

```
-0x1.e51b67p+0 0x1.0b18ef5p+8 0x1.9c6075p+8 -0x1.190d44p+4
-0x1.e4f7838p+0 0x1.0b6446dp+8 0x1.9d779b8p+8 -0x1.16436ap+3
-0x1.e4555bp+0 0x1.0b6d446p+8 0x1.9e28c4ap+8 -0x1.1f8b0ep+3
-0x1.e3b9598p+0 0x1.0b7982cp+8 0x1.9edf5f8p+8 -0x1.f80bc6p+2
-0x1.e2f5896p+0 0x1.0b70bd7p+8 0x1.9f75c6ap+8 -0x1.07390ep+3
-0x1.e21d2dep+0 0x1.0b5961cp+8 0x1.9fef6e6p+8 -0x1.031012p+3
-0x1.e225b96p+0 0x1.0bbc104p+8 0x1.a12c75cp+8 -0x1.06951cp+3
-0x1.e17ec4cp+0 0x1.0bc35b7p+8 0x1.a1de5a6p+8 -0x1.25f138p+3
-0x1.e0e7f36p+0 0x1.0c140edp+8 0x1.a300c22p+8 -0x1.417644p+3
-0x1.e0e7e0ap+0 0x1.0c7474fp+8 0x1.a43f084p+8 -0x1.359f22p+3
-0x1.e076e6cp+0 0x1.0c93aebp+8 0x1.a50efaap+8 -0x1.00e406p+4
-0x1.e1c339cp+0 0x1.0ec7d62p+8 0x1.ab2777p+8 -0x1.1b6134p+3
-0x1.e0614eap+0 0x1.0e669d1p+8 0x1.ab301b8p+8 -0x1.6a997cp+2
-0x1.e01577p+0 0x1.0e9f2e5p+8 0x1.ac33c36p+8 -0x1.62eb42p+2
-0x1.de237dcp+0 0x1.0df5506p+8 0x1.abd2c42p+8 -0x1.8951c2p+2
```

I write this `c++` code without any success:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    float a, b, c, d;

    std::ifstream ifs("data.txt");

    int n = 0;
    while(ifs >> std::hex >> a
              >> std::hex >> b
              >> std::hex >> c
              >> std::hex >> d)
    {
        std::cout << a << " "
                  << b << " "
                  << c << " "
                  << d << std::endl;
        ++n;
    }
    std::cout << "n=" << n << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

**Edit**: I tried with `std::hexfloat` instead but it's still not working with `gcc` as shown [in this example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lQEYCXM8yfAIHCtG).

Comment: Handy reading: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed Specifically you want `hexfloat`.

Comment: What do you mean by *without any success*?

Comment: I mean that the program only prints `n=0` instead of printing the corresponding float values of the files

Comment: Are you willing to drop into C for a while?  I've been so fixated on doing this in C++, I completely forgot that `scanf`'s `%a` format should eat this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `-0x1.e51b67p+0` gobble-de-gook is the output of [`std::hexfloat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed), an addition to C++'s Standard Library in the C++ 11 Standard Revision.

If you replace

```
while(ifs >> std::hex >> a
          >> std::hex >> b
          >> std::hex >> c
          >> std::hex >> d)
```

with

```
while(ifs >> std::hexfloat >> a
          >> std::hexfloat >> b
          >> std::hexfloat >> c
          >> std::hexfloat >> d)
```

and your compiler supports C++11 and `hexfloat` (G++ was a bit laggy in this) you should be good to go.

Edit: G++ was laggy in including `std::hexfloat` in the headers. Unfortunately as of today, GCC 8.2, support for `std::hexfloat` is incomplete and not working. This answer does not work for the Asker.

Edit 2: I deserve to fall on my sword for this, but fortunately I don't have a sword. In my obsessive digging into why this didn't work in C++ and trying to find a polite way to make this work in C++, I completely forgot the fact that this works just fine in C.

Since `std::hexfloat` is held up while the wording of the C++ Standard is sorted out, let's follow the Git-R Done! Principle, use C, and wrap it up in a function so it can easily be replaced with idiomatic C++ later.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    float a, b, c, d;

    FILE *f = fopen("data.txt", "r");

    if (f == NULL)
    {
        std::cerr << "Unable to open file."
        return -1;
    }
    int n = 0;
    while(fscanf(f, "%a %a %a %a", &a, &b, &c, &d) == 4)
    {
        std::cout << a << " "
                  << b << " "
                  << c << " "
                  << d << std::endl;
        ++n;
    }
    std::cout << "n=" << n << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it does not seem to work: [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lQEYCXM8yfAIHCtG)

Comment: @T.L Odd. Clang and Visual Studio handle it correctly. Could be GCC is still wonky, or perhaps there is some disagreement over how to interpret the Standard. I'll have to look at this a bit more.

Comment: Is ifstream smart enough to handle the spaces in between the values? what you've really got is a source CSV file (in this case, the C stands for Common) - Not using ifstream frequently I'm not entirely sure if it will handle this correctly.

Comment: could be a root cause why GCC still is not able to handle "hexFloat" properly: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59987

Comment: @Phill the `>>` operator reads from a stream until it finds an input that does not fit the specified parsing rules or the next whitespace. It should handle this case just fine.

Comment: @AlexanderPaderin Well doesn't that suck. It's still marked as non-functional. Says the same in GCC's big support list: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#manual.intro.status.iso

Comment: @user4481301 yes it does, but im not actually surprised, this is how things go in cpp world for decades...

Comment: Grinding down, this does look like a [disagreement over how the Standard is worded and how `hexfloat` should be implemented](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2381). A good answer to this that looks after Asker's short-term interests, which I probably won't have time to write before someone else does, will be to read as `string`, manually parse into the three pieces, convert the pieces, and assemble.

Answer (score 4):

seems GCC is still not able to handle "hexFloat" properly, check out gcc bug tracker:

https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59987

How about this simple alternative solution?

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const char *data = "-0x1.e51b67p+0 0x1.0b18ef5p+8 0x1.9c6075p+8 -0x1.190d44p+4 -0x1.e4f7838p+0 0x1.0b6446dp+8 0x1.9d779b8p+8 -0x1.16436ap+3";

    char *end;
    for (float f = strtof(data, &end); data != end; f = strtof(data, &end))
    {
        data = end;
        if (errno == ERANGE){
            printf("range error, got ");
            errno = 0;
        }
        printf("%a\n", f);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/69MpeNKexPWaOiZc

Comment: You should include the relevant parts of your linked code in you answer so that it stays self contained.  See [answer], particularly the "Provide context for links" section.